# redmi device restarting when trying to put creadentials in entry control in xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, miui

I am getting an issue with Entry field on a particular device (Xiaomi Note7 Pro) that is when I try to put value in the entry field it will cause restart the MIUI of device (Xiaomi Note7 Pro). I have done some digging but did not find any solution yet. Please help me out with this issue.

I have tried to change the keyboard types as well in entry but still didn't get any success. Below is the sample of entry control xaml:

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <controls:ExtEntry x:Name="txtUsername" 
                       Placeholder="Username" 
                       Keyboard="Email" 
                       Text="{Binding Username}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource EntryImage}"/>
    <Image Source="usericon"
           Style="{StaticResource RightImageIcon}"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Below is the code for my ExtEntry (Renderer):

```cs
public class CustomEntry : EntryRenderer
{
    ExtEntry element;

    public CustomEntry(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null) return;

        element = (ExtEntry)this.Element;

        var editText = this.Control;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Image))
        {
            switch (element.ImageAlignment)
            {
                case ImageAlignment.Left:
                    editText.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                        GetDrawable(element.Image), null, null, null);

                    break;
                case ImageAlignment.Right:
                    editText.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                        null, null, GetDrawable(element.Image), null);

                    break;
            }
        }
        editText.CompoundDrawablePadding = 25;

        // Control.Background.SetColorFilter(element.LineColor.ToAndroid(),
        //     PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);

        Control.FocusChange += Control_FocusChange;

        if (element.IsBorderVisible)
        {
            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
            gd.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
            gd.SetCornerRadius(3);
            gd.SetStroke(3, Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(188, 196, 205));
            Control.SetBackground(gd);
        }

        Control.CustomSelectionActionModeCallback = new Callback();
        Control.SetPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
        Control.LongClickable = false;
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, 
        PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (e.PropertyName.Equals(nameof(element.Image)))
        {
            var editText = this.Control;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Image))
            {
                switch (element.ImageAlignment)
                {
                    case ImageAlignment.Left:
                        editText.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                            GetDrawable(element.Image), null, null, null);

                        break;
                    case ImageAlignment.Right:
                        editText.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, 
                            GetDrawable(element.Image), null);

                        break;
                }
            }
            editText.CompoundDrawablePadding = 25;
        }
    }

    private void Control_FocusChange(object sender, FocusChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Control.HasFocus)
        {
            if (element.IsBorderVisible)
            {
                GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                gd.SetStroke(3, Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(29, 74, 147));
                Control.SetBackground(gd);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (element.IsBorderVisible)
            {
                GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                gd.SetStroke(3, Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(188, 196, 205));
                Control.SetBackground(gd);
            }
        }
    }

    private Drawable GetDrawable(string imageEntryImage)
    {
        int resID = Resources.GetIdentifier(imageEntryImage, 
            "drawable", this.Context.PackageName);

        var drawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this.Context, resID);
        var bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, 
            element.ImageHeight, element.ImageWidth, true));

        return d;
    }
}
```

Please someone help me out with this issue. I have tried many things to fix this but didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: Could you provide some details of `ExtEntry`? Have you test on another device? Do you get the same error?

Comment: On other devices it is working properly

Comment: I guess this issue is caused by the specific device. You need to check the specific of this device.

Comment: If, i rename the bundle name then, it will work fine until next update